# Increase the Size Limit of Windows Command Args

Tags: java, windows

I am running a competition on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) called [Good Versus Evil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33137/18487). When I wrote the challenge, I did not anticipate the 50+ submissions I now have. I must now somehow send a Windows command that is slightly larger than 58,000 characters, and I expect the number to grow. Is this even possible?

The code I am using to execute other submissions is as follows (in Java):

```java
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + " " + history);
```

- `command` is something like `python angel.py` or `cscript //nologo PiHart.vbs`
- `history` is the argument that grows larger than Windows can handle

When the command plus the history grows larger than about 32,000 characters, I get an IOException:

> CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Keep in mind that I can't just change the rules. The PPCG community is intolerant of rule changes that invalidate existing submissions. The temporary rule that I have in place just divides the submissions into manageable pods and then runs the competition in batches. This does not break any submissions, but it could hurt submissions who were expecting a larger play group.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit, I haven't looked at the cgse question in detail, but would it be too much work for the contestants to just change the input scheme from command line arguments to stdin?

Because the maximum command-line length limit of 32K [is effectively unchangeable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx).

**EDIT:** Okay, looking into the answers a bit, they are mostly trivial enough (and in high-level languages), so that changing the input format is *probably* tolerable. If in doubt, it could be done by you to not bother the original implementers (there are some who pop up to post an answer and never react to comments again, who likely wouldn't change their code either).

Another option: How many of those answers are Windows-specific? I think on Linux the command line length limit is tweakable. I'm fairly alone as a PowerShell golfer on that site and most people tend to write in languages that are portable to other OSes as well (those tend to garner most upvotes, too). You might try running most submissions on Linux and fix the Windows-specific ones for a different input format. Still a lot of work on your part, but perhaps easier to justify than making everyone else do more work.

Comment: Asking 57 people to change the input format of 57 programs is a bit much. Anyone who didn't comply would simply be disqualified. I still think your answer is correct, but maybe someone else has a more useful workaround that makes sends an argument that didn't necessarily come from the command line. If the change is transparent to the program, that's all that matters to me.

Answer (score -1):

You could log a bug to Microsoft and they might fix it for you one day, assuming they don't point out this might break backward compatibility which is a good excuse not to fix a bug.

Or you could write the commands to a batch file and run the batch file ;)

Comment: Batch files have only an 8K length limit for command lines. That's way worse than CreateProcess. Which is unfixable, too, because it depends on the layout of `UNICODE_STRING`